# How to find out the exceptions will be thrown in method?

Tags: sql, exception, methods, max

I have this code and this exception handling. How to find out all possible exceptions will be thrown and handle it? my handling isn't correct? I think about SQLException, NullPointer- etc. I need to find the maximum number by year from 3 tables. Which exceptions can be?

```
public Integer getMaxNumberByYear(String year){

        String queryStr = "SELECT MAX(trip_card_number)\n" +
                "  FROM (SELECT trip_card_number FROM employee_trip_cards\n" +
                "        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM card_Issue_Date) = '" + year + "'\n" +
                "        UNION ALL\n" +
                "        SELECT trip_card_number FROM postgraduate_trip_cards\n" +
                "        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM card_Issue_Date) = '" + year + "'\n" +
                "        UNION ALL\n" +
                "        SELECT trip_card_number FROM students_trip_cards \n" +
                "        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM card_Issue_Date) = '" + year + "'\n" +
                "        )";

        try {

            Integer result = ((BigDecimal) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryStr).uniqueResult()).intValue();

            if (result==null){
                throw new NullPointerException("Can't find the maximum");
            }

            return result;

        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utils.getSystemLogger().log(e);
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should review the signature of `createSQLQuery()` to see what exceptions it might be throwing.

Comment: Seems strange that you throw an exception just to catch it and return 0. Why not return zero in the if statement?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it has only HibernateException. It's ok if i set result by 0 if exception will be thrown?

Comment: Why different trip_cards tables? Consider one common trip_cards table.

Comment: @jarlh There are different entities with one identical field

Comment: I hope you are not trying to create a "unique" number using that code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why? what's wrong?

Comment: Because it won't work correctly with concurrent transactions (or if you _can_ make it work, it will be slow as hell). If you want to generate unique numbers use a database sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to throw a NullPointerException and then catch it in the same method. What you have written looks like handling logic with exceptions, which is not good. Consider writing:

```
    if (result==null){
       Utils.getSystemLogger().log("Can't find the maximum");
       return 0;
    } 
    return result;
```

if 0 is an allowed return value for the method, or do not catch the exception otherwise.

You do not have to think ahead and find all the possible exceptions. If you do not know the possible exceptions yet, you also do not know how to recover from them, thus it is better to let them be thrown and debug later.